# MVC - Application root appears twice in url using Url.Content/Url.Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have several mvc applications on the same domain, each have their own directory.

mydomain.com/app1
mydomain.com/app2
etc..

When using Url.Content() and Url.Action() when at the root level, 'app1' part is repeated twice in the urls.

```
// code used to generate the links
<%= Url.Action("tetris", "Apps") %>
```

```
Page Url:               mydomain.com/app1/
rendered link (broken): mydomain.com/app1/app1/Apps.aspx/tetris

application root appears twice in the rendered url when at the root directory
```

```
Page Url:               mydomain.com/app1/home.aspx/
rendered link (works):  mydomain.com/app1/Apps.aspx/tetris

application root appears once - everything works as expected
```

my routes - I'm using the routes from [Phil haacks blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx)

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}.aspx/{action}/{id}",
    new { action = "Index", id = "" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Root",
    "",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because applications process web.configs in order of inner most director to outer most directory.

You have two options to fix this behavior.

1. Specify the namespaces you want the routes to apply to either in the root directory or your sub-directories.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504958.aspx

   routes.MapRoute(
       "Root", "", new {...}, 
       new[] { "MyNamespace.For.Root" }
   );
2. Or in the root directory specify your sub-directories as ignored routes using.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505203.aspx

   routes.IgnoreRoute("/app1");
   routes.IgnoreRoute("/app2");

Comment: 1. I don't understand this, there is only one namespace, and one place to define routes, global.asax.cs. Could you eleborate on this?

2. routes.IgnoreRoute("/app1") throws an exception: routeUrl cannot start with '~' or '/'.

Comment: You are having problems because your root Global.asax file is processing the URL's for your sub-apps.  This is what you need to prevent.  You have been very vague in your question about if the sub-applications are actual virtual applications in IIS or if they are just parts of one application hosted at the root.  Does your "app1" for instance have its own Global.asax and Web.config?

Answer (score 0):

When I had this issue it was because someone used `RouteArea["app1"]` attribute on the Controller but also included it on the action `GET["apps1/Detail"]` instead of just `GET["Detail"]`