# URL forwarding+masking triggers double root directory for Url.Content() & Html.Action() under ASP.NET MVC 3 RC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-masking

(Note: tried to look for similar question, but the closest one doesn't seem to match my question still. i.e. [MVC - Application root appears twice in url using Url.Content/Url.Action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217697/mvc-application-root-appears-twice-in-url-using-url-content-url-action) )

I currently have two ASP.NET MVC 3 RC apps running under one domain i.e.

mydomain.com/app1

mydomain.com/app2

Now, because it is a separate app, I signed up for another domain name and enabled mask forwarding to one of the apps
(i.e. http://foo.com would load http://mydomain.com/app1 and in the browser, it will only show http://foo.com, not http://mydomain.com/app1)

Well, that's where MVC starts to have some complaints. Both Url.Content() & Html.Action() generate unexpected URLs.
For example, in the case of Html.Action(), if I have `@Html.ActionLink("About", "Index", "About")`, I expect http://foo.com/about, but end up getting http://foo.com/**app1**/about

Because http://foo.com/app1/about translates into http://mydomain.com/app1/app1/about, obviously the link won't work.

Similarly, for Url.Content, if I have `href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")"`, the browser will fail to load the stylesheet, because it thinks the location is at http://foo.com/**app1**/Content/Site.css, instead of http://foo.com/Content/Site.css

Is there a way, I can make MVC forget about its starting directory (i.e. remove "**app1/**" from its generated URL?)

Thanks for reading, and please let me know if additional information is needed here.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, there are workarounds.

For Url.Content(), we will simply remove "~" from `Url.Content("~/...")`, so to get rid of that relative path (i.e. **/app1**)

As for Html.ActionLink(), the solution seems messy, because relative path is always assumed, so the workaround here is temporary. Anyone has a better solution out there?

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLinkAbsolute(
                    this HtmlHelper<dynamic> htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName)
                {
                    MvcHtmlString result = LinkExtensions.ActionLink(htmlHelper, linkText, actionName, controllerName);
                    result = new MvcHtmlString(result.ToHtmlString().Replace(VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~"), String.Empty)); 
                    return result;
                }
```

The workaround here is not without its consequence. In order to support URL masking, and disregard the relative path, http://mydomain.com/app1 will not generate expected link, because it will always remove the relative path. It is not perfect, but that's a downside I can live with.